# PCFG vs SR Parser

Tags: stanford-nlp

It looks like stanfordnlp has these SR models for some time.
I am really new to NLP but we are currently using PCFG parser and we are having serious performance issues( that we cut down the parse length to 35)

1. I was thinking if we could try using SR. I tried it with POS tagger from stanford(english-left3words-distsim.tagger)
   Would you know how SR is on accuracy vs PCFG? 
   I also find sentence root detection issues with SR and dep parse: Example:
   Michael Jeffrey Jordan, also known by his initials, MJ, is an American former professional basketball player, entrepreneur, and current majority owner and chairman of the Charlotte Bobcats
   The PCFG is really accurate with the root and detects player as the root.
2. Would also appreciate a little insight on the NN people use e.g.(https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2014-November/006513.html)  in  above post.
   Do I need to use another tagger like - left3words with this?
   I am sorry if this sounds a little naive.
   But all I want is a correct sentence root and its dependencies.
   Does POS tagging upfront make it fast?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't understand question #2. Can you reword this? The shift-reduce constituency parser does not use the neural-net architecture which the NNDep dependency parser uses.

Answer (score 0):

1. The English shift-reduce parser shipped with CoreNLP is actually slightly better than the PCFG parser on our test data. You can see performance metrics at the bottom of the [shift-reduce parser homepage](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml).
2. I've asked for clarification in a comment above.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree with that. I see for example for the following sentence -                                                                                                Adam Richard Sandler (born September 9, 1966) is an American actor, comedian, screenwriter, entrepreneur, film producer and musician                                Whereas PCFG sentence root - Actor has outgoing edges of comedian, screenwriter,...musician; for SR parser it  doesn't link comedian, musician. What combination does the following use:http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

Comment: All we can say for certain is this: on one of the standard parsing test sets, the SR parser does a bit better on average. Your mileage may significantly vary based on the data you're working with.

Comment: "What combination does the [parser demo] use?" It uses the basic English PCFG parser.